# What is bounds propagation

Tags: prolog, clpfd

I am trying to figure out what is bounds propagation in clpfd, but cannot seem to find a good explanation anywhere.

I am revising for Prolog and clpfd and came across this question, but looking at the lecture notes it does not make sense to me. Could someone please explain the actual meaning of bounds propagation and what it is used for.

Here is the question I am referring to:

When the following Prolog program

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
bounds(X, Y, Z) :-
   X in 1..5,
   Y in 1..2,
   Z in 3..5,
   X #= Y + Z.
```

is queried it gives the answer:

```
?- bounds(X, Y, Z).
X in 4..5,
Y in 1..2,
Z in 3..4.
```

Explain how bounds propagation can be applied to infer this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Bounds propagation is a form of propagation that the constraint solver **automatically** applies for you. The key point, for users, is that they need *not* understand the algorithm behind it, but can simply rely on the constraint solver to do the work for them. In the result you show, the solver has *already* applied this form of propagation.

To understand what the constraint solver is doing for you, here is a start:

We know:

- `Y` is *at least* **1**
- `Z` is *at least* **3**
- `X` is the **sum** of `Y` and `Z`.

**Hence** (exercise: *Why*?): `X` is *at least* **4**.

Then, repeat this reasoning for all other variables, for both upper **and** lower bounds!

Repeat this until no more domain elements can be removed from any of the variables, which is called a *fix point* of the propagation. When this is done, you have established *bounds consistency*.